# Python: How to print a list with labels for each item within the list

Tags: python, list, file

I am doing a python project for my Intro to CSC class. We are given a .txt file that is basically 200,000 lines of single words. We have to read in the file line by line, and count how many times each letter in the alphabet appears as the first letter of a word. I have the count figured out and stored in a list. But now I need to print it in the format

```
"a:10,898 b:9,950 c:17,045 d:10,596 e:8,735
f:11,257 .... "
```

Another aspect is that it has to print 5 of the letter counts per line, as I did above.

This is what I am working with so far...

```
def main():
    file_name = open('dictionary.txt', 'r').readlines()
counter = 0
    totals = [0]*26
    alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
    for i in file_name:
        for n in range(0,26):
            if i.startswith(alphabet[n]):
                totals[n] = totals[n]+1
    print(totals)

main()
```

This code currently outputs

```
[10898, 9950, 17045, 10675, 7421, 7138, 5998, 6619, 6619, 7128, 1505, 1948, 5393, 10264, 4688, 6079, 15418, 890, 10790, 20542, 9463, 5615, 2924, 3911, 142, 658]
```

Comment: Thought I should add that this is what its giving me at the moment

[10898, 9950, 17045, 10675, 7421, 7138, 5998, 6619, 6619, 7128, 1505, 1948, 5393, 10264, 4688, 6079, 15418, 890, 10790, 20542, 9463, 5615, 2924, 3911, 142, 658]

Answer (score 1):

I would *highly* recommend using a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) to store the counts. It will greatly simplify your code, and make it *much* faster. I'll leave that as an exercise for you since this is clearly homework. (other hint: [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is even better). In addition, right now your code is only correct for lowercase letters, not uppercase ones. You need to add additional logic to either treat uppercase letters as lowercase ones, or treat them independently. Right now you just ignore them.

Having said that, the following will get it done for your current format:

```
print(', '.join('{}:{}'.format(letter, count) for letter, count in zip(alphabet, total)))
```

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) takes *n* lists and generates a new list of tuples with *n* elements, with each element coming from one of the input lists. [`join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) concatenates a list of strings together using the supplied separator. And [`format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-formatting) does string interpolation to fill in values in a string with the provided ones using format specifiers.

Comment: In the lab assignment my professor included a few hints. These were the first two... 

"Say w is a word in the list words, to translate the first letter, a-z, to the range 0-25 use the builtin function ord() and subract this value from the ordinal value of 'a'.       
ord(w[0])-ord('a')   
Use a list of 26 zeros to hold the count for each letter. The indices can map to letters of the alphabet. Increment the index corresponding to the first letter of each word in the dictionary. "

I didn't quite understand what he meant.

Comment: @zachcapp `ord()` returns the ASCII/UTF8 value of a character. So, for example, `ord('a') == 97`. In the ASCII/UTF8 character space, all of the lowercase alphabet is contiguous beginning with `'a'` at `97`, and ending with `'z'` at `122`. If I subtract the `ord()` value of `'a'` from the `ord()` value of any other lower case letter, I will get a number in the range `0-25`, which would allow you to directly index into an array of counts.

Comment: Also please accept the answer (click the grey checkmark next to it) if it solved your problem so that others that might have similar problems know this solved it.

Comment: Thanks. Now about the other detail of my question.. How do I get it to start a new line after every 5 items printed?

Answer (score 0):

**python 3.4**

the solution is to read the line of the file into words variable below in cycle and use Counter

```
from collections import Counter
import string

words = 'this is a test of functionality'
result = Counter(map(lambda x: x[0], words.split(' ')))
words = 'and this is also very cool'
result = result + Counter(map(lambda x: x[0], words.split(' ')))

counters = ['{letter}:{value}'.format(letter=x, value=result.get(x, 0)) for x in string.ascii_lowercase]
```

if you print **counters**:

> ['a:3', 'b:0', 'c:1', 'd:0', 'e:0', 'f:1', 'g:0', 'h:0', 'i:2', 'j:0', 'k:0', 'l:0', 'm:0', 'n:0', 'o:1', 'p:0', 'q:0', 'r:0', 's:0', 't:3', 'u:0', 'v:1', 'w:0', 'x:0', 'y:0', 'z:0']